# Using `kill` to trigger a parent's `waitpid`

Tags: c, shell, posix

I'm using `sigaction(SIGTSTP, &ctrlz_signal, NULL);` to ensure I can catch `Ctrl-Z`.

```
void ctrlz_signal(int sigNo) {
    printf("Caught Ctrl-Z  |  curr_chld=%d\n", CURR_CHILD);
    if(CURR_CHILD != 0) kill(CURR_CHILD, SIGTSTP);
}
```

`CURR_CHILD` is set through forking:

```
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &ctrlz_signal, NULL);

    int         status;
    CURR_CHILD = fork();


    if (CURR_CHILD < 0) {
        // ...

    } else if (CURR_CHILD == 0) {  // child
        // exec(...)

    } else {  // back in parent
        waitpid(CURR_CHILD, &status, 0);  // wait for child to finish
        // ...
    }
```

It seems like it successfully stops the child process, but then it doesn't trigger the parent's `waitpid`. I would've thought there would be a signal sent to the parent when I'd use this `kill` function, but it seems like it isn't since my "shell" gets stuck on that `waitpid` line.

How do I make it so that, once `Ctrl-Z` is pressed, the process running an `exec` command (which is a child, at that point) should be put in the background (stopped), and then the parent process should gain back its control over the flow of the program ?

Comment: Using `printf()` in a signal handler is undefined, btw. And you should read the manpage for `waitpid()` again, paying attention to the section on the options argument.

Comment: @Shawn you helped me out, thank you! Feel free to post about how `WUNTRACED` was the flag that I needed in `waitpid` and I'll mark it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is not an [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) function (as it is not re-entrant) and therefore must not be used in a signal handler. Using such functions will lead to undefined behavior.

If you want a child process that is not traced with `ptrace` to return, you have to specify the `WUNTRACED` option when you use [`waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid).

Alternatively, you can use [`ptrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) with the `PTRACE_TRACEME` option, so that it will provide status for the child process even if the `WUNTRACED` option is not specified in the `waitpid` call.